# android: using adjustPan and without scrolling the title bar

Tags: android, titlebar, adjustpan

I'm using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in my `manifest.xml`.
It's doing me the job just fine but there is something retarded about it.
when i focus an `EditText` view that's, say in the bottom half of the screen, the title bar is also scrolled with the content of the activity.

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeNuj.png)

all i want is to freeze/float the title bar in place when scrolling the content. just like this:

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWsWV.png)

and no, I don't want to use `adjustResize` It overlaps views on top of each other

any help is greatly appreciated, been looking for the answer for a long time.

Comment: I'm using a `RelativeLayout` in my mainActivity.xml,, that could be the reason views overlap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

Simply changing the root view in the layout xml file to a `ScrollView` does the job.

I don't even need to specify `android:windowSoftInputMode`

Of course I have to have everything else in a single layout as the child of the `ScrollView`

**Edit**

your .xml file should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    ... >
    <LinearLayout>    // could be any other layout but linear works well here
        //insert all other views of the activity here
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you please show your code! I'm facing the same problem but unable to solve with given answer.

Comment: @Ammar sorry for the the delay, check the answer again.
don't forget to up-vote it plz

Comment: Where should I be placing the custom titlebar in this xml?

Comment: sorry i dont know the answer to that, i stopped coding for a while and got rusty, i hope a google search can help u

Answer (score -1):

The answer suggested by Ace is essentially what is needed. My answer just aims to make things a little clearer.

There are two things you need to do. Firstly in the Manifest set the following on the activity. `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

Then, in the activity's layout you'll want to set a ScrollView beneath the Toolbar/Title Bar, as shown in the code below.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        .../>

    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ...>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                ...>
           </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

From what I understand, here's how it works.
When you open the soft keyboard on your device, it will 'adjustResize' the layout of the activity. As the layout sits in a ScrollView, this is the part which is resized, and made smaller. Therefore the Toolbar/Titlebar will stay in place and the layout in the ScrollView will be scrollable when the keyboard is shown.

Comment: doesnt work, the relative layout also moves, using adustpan though, but same principle here